# Create an ownerOnly function in a contract B that can only be called through another contract A by setting B's owner to be the A contract

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I don't know to describe my question. So I will try to explain it here. I'm working with truffle.
I have a Contract A that deploys a Contract B.
A passes it's address to B.
B's owner is set to the address of A.
Inside B there is a function foo() that requires the caller to be the owner.

My question is this: Can I call foo() from truffle like this ?

```
B.foo( {from: A.address} )
```

Or is it the case that the foo() function is now only callable through the contract itself, e.g. with an A's fooA() function that calls B.foo() ?

I provide an example code below.

```
contract B {
  address private immutable ownerOfB;

  modifier ownerOnly  {
    require (msg.sender == ownerOfB, 
      "ONLY OWNER(S) ALLOWED TO DO THAT.");
    _;
  }
  constructor(address _owner) {
    ownerOfB = _owner;
  }
  function fooB() ownerOnly public {
    // do something
  }
}

contract A {
  
  address private immutable ownerOfA;
  B b;

  contructor() {
    ownerOfA = msg.sender;
    b = new B( address(this) );
  }
  
  function fooA() {
    fooB()
  }
}
```

Now if I use this code in truffle with the default account settings , A's owner will be accounts[0] and B's owner will be A.address. The function fooB() can be called through fooA() but cannot be called from truffle directly like this: `B.foo( {from: A.address} );` even if we were to get an instance of the B contract in truffle with something like

```
aContr = await A.deployed();
bContr = await B.at( a.b() );
```

and then to call B.foo:

```
bContr.fooB( {from: aContr.address} )  --> throws Error "sender address not recognized"
```

Is this correct behaviour or is it relevant to truffle only?

PS. In my migration file I only deploy the A contract.

Answer (score 0):

My question is totally wrong, I have made the assumption that a contract may be the initiator of a transaction (tx.origin being a contract) which obviously can't be true. I don't know how to delete the question, so I posted an answer.

Comment: You are correct. To send a transaction you need to sign it, since contracts do not have private keys then they can't sign a transaction.